# Вытащить скрытое поле из ListView и записать в AlertDialog

Tags: android, java, sqlite, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Моя работа проходит с ***Java*** в ***Android Studio***. Для работы с БД использую ***SQLite***.

Суть вопроса заключается в том, что у меня есть таблица с определенными полями (время, количество сахара, примечание). Имеется ***ListView***, где отображаются только 2 поля из этой таблицы (время и количество сахара). При нажатии на определенный элемент ***ListView*** должно выводится в ***AlertDialog*** 3-е поле, которое не указано в ***ListView***. То бишь, при нажатии на определенный элемент мне нужно считать 3-е поле (примечание), которое не было выведено в ***ListView*** и вывести ***AlertDialog***.

Как мне считать это поле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему так:

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClicked = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final TextView notes = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hidden_note);
            final String note = notes.getText().toString();

            alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("Примітка")  // заголовок
                    .setMessage(note) // сообщение
                    .setNeutralButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {

                        }
                    });

            alertDialogBuilder.show();
        }
    };
```